# Customized text as well as a formula in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet that has a number of drop downs and then larger merged cells for comments. What I want to happen is if the drop down choice is "blank" the comment cells will display two asterisk (or brackets). After those two asterisks are placed in the cell or not placed (dependent on the drop down choice), I would like to allow the user to input text between those two asterisks and outside of them in that same cell.

As of now I input them manually because I am not sure how to have a formula and customized text (that is usually different) in a cell. Is there a formula or coding to do so? Or possibly redirect a formula in one cell to the other so you can also type content?

Comment: Show sample data with before and after results.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @urdearboy is it possible to have customized text as well as a formula in a single cell is my main question.

Comment: okay i'm going to delete my old answer and submit a new one. basically, you want to set a default value of `**` in the comments cell if the corresponding dropdown cell is set to `Material`, right? I think this can only be accomplished via VBA

Comment: That is correct Marc thanks! There are a few drop downs that feed to the one comment section. If any one of those drop downs show "Material" it will display just one "**". If you could incorporate that it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here's my third attempt at interpreting your question. I got the impression that really what you wanted was to set a "default value" to the comment cell if it's corresponding drop down was "Material".

In this scenario, the dropdowns exist in `A1:A10` and the comments are in `B1:B10`.

Because of the nature of this code, if any of the dropdowns are **already set** to "Material" you'll have to change it to something else and then back to material to get the default value to pop back up.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'will trigger if the user makes a change to any cell A1 through A10, the dropdown cells
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value2 = "Material" Then
            'assumes the comment cell is one column to the right
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = "**"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```